# Save the result of ls command in the remote SFTP server on local machine

Tags: linux, bash, sftp, expect, ls

I have seen [How do I pipe the output of an LS on remote server to the local filesystem via SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150451/how-do-i-pipe-the-output-of-an-ls-on-remote-server-to-the-local-filesystem-via-s), but I am not satisfied with answer. I connect to remote SFTP server and I will do `ls` there. I want to have the result of `ls` on my local machine. I don't want any thing extra to be saved, only the result of `ls` command. Can I save the result to a variable accessible on the local machine?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp myuser@myftp.mydomain.com
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\n";
expect "sftp>"
send  "ls\n"  //save here
interact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, with a more "traditional" approach that involves opening a file for writing the desired output (I like @kastelian 's log_file idea, though):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp myuser@myftp.mydomain.com
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\n";
expect "sftp>"

set file [open /tmp/ls-output w]     ;# open for writing and set file identifier

expect ".*"     ;# match anything in buffer so as to clear it

send  "ls\r"

expect {
    "sftp>" {
        puts $file $expect_out(buffer)  ;# save to file buffer contents since last match (clear) until this match (sftp> prompt)
    }
    timeout {     ;# somewhat elegant way to die if something goes wrong
        puts $file "Error: expect block timed out"
    }
}

close $file

interact
```

The resulting file will hold the same two extra lines as in the log_file proposed solution: the ls command at the top, and the sftp> prompt at the bottom, but you should be able to deal with those as you like.

I have tested this and it works.

Let me know if it helped!

Comment: Thanks James. This file is on local machine correct? I dont want to create a file on remote machine

Comment: That's correct, file is on local machine (where expect script runs), *not* on remote. You can edit the path and its name from what I put (/tmp/ls-output) to whatever/wherever you prefer (/home, etc).

Answer (score 4):

Try sending `ls` output to the log file:

```
spawn sftp myuser@myftp.mydomain.com
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\n";
expect "sftp>"
log_file -noappend ls.out
send  "ls\n"  //save here
expect "sftp>"
log_file
interact
```

`log_file -noappend ls.out` triggers logging program output, and later `log_file` without arguments turns it off. Need to expect another `sftp` prompt otherwise it won't log the output.

There will be two extra lines in log – first line is `ls` command itself, last line is `sftp>` prompt. You can filter them out with something like `sed -n '$d;2,$p' log.out`. Then you can slurp the contents of the file into shell variable, remove temp file, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo 'ls -1' | sftp <hostname> > files.txt`. Or, if you really want a shell variable (not recommended if you have a long file list), try `varname=$(echo 'ls -1' | sftp <hostname>)`.

Comment: Thanks I am using expect script. Do you know how to do it in expect. I will update it in the question